# How do I replace spaces with std::regex_replace between markers using non-capture groups?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++, regex-group

I'm trying to eliminate whitespaces in a string with a regular expression. From the following snippet:

```
std::string in = "abc>  <def\n"
                 "xyz>      \n";
std::regex re = R"((?:>)\s+(?:<)|\s+$)";
std::string out = std::regex_replace(in, re, "(newcontent)");
```

I'm expecting `out` to contain

```
abc>(newcontent)<def
xyz>(newcontent)
```

but, alas, I get

```
abc(newcontent)def
xyz>(newcontent)
```

instead. To me it seems that the non-capture sequence `(?:...)` isn't working. I've tried to modify the program with extensions as `std::regex re ("....", std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::nosubs);` and appending `, std::regex_constants::format_default` to `regex_replace` to no avail. Can this be a library implementation problem or am I at fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `>` and `<` are captured, they can be written back.
This way there are no assertion compatibility issues.

```
(>)\s+(<)|\s+$
```

replace

```
$1(newcontent)$2
```

https://regex101.com/r/dOjUlw/1